# How to electronically calculate alcoholic level of a liquid

Tags: alcohols, conductivity

Is there any way to estimate the alcohol content of a drink with an electric test? Is alcohol in a liquid (e.g wine) dependent on the drink's conductivity?

Comment: I doubt if conductivity will be a reliable measure. The presence of acids and other ionic species in different wines or alcoholic drinks is likely to affect conductivity much more than alcohol content. Traditionally, alcohol content is determined from the specific gravity of the liquid, measured using a hydrometer (the presence of sugar also affects the reading) - but if you want an electronic readout (e.g. for continuous monitoring) perhaps index of refraction would work (if the beverage is not dark or murky).

Comment: If fact, I asking myself if it would be possible to get the alcohol as well as residual sugar and acidity of a wine, with a cheap sensor that you may put in a glass of wine. What is your opinion ?